# View set as inputAccessoryView throws exception when added back into normal view

Tags: ios, ios8, uikeyboard, inputaccessoryview

I have a text view, some decorations etc. in a view and I want that view to dock on keyboard, just like any other messaging app.

When I'm about to display my text view, here is how I attach my view to the keyboard:

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    UIView *inputView = self.textInputView; //connected at IB outlet from storyboard, also contains the text view itself.
    constraintsOfTextInputView = [self constraintsRelatedToView:inputView]; //to be able to add them again
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:self.textInputView];
    textView.inputAccessoryView = inputView;
    editingTextView = textView;
    return YES;
}
```

And when dismissing:

```
//using notification hook for UIKeyboardWillHideNotification because
//textView[Will|Did]EndEditing is called too late

-(void)keyboardWillHide{
    if(editingTextView && constraintsOfTextInputView){
        editingTextView.inputAccessoryView = nil;
        [self.textInputView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:self.textInputView]; <--- EXCEPTION
        [self.view addConstraints:constraintsOfTextInputView];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

        editingTextView = nil;
        constraintsOfTextInputView = nil;
    }
}
```

Even though I'm doing exactly the opposite of what I do when adding, I'm getting this exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:
<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x13307ba20> should have parent view
controller:<ULPostViewController: 0x1307a7c00> but actual parent is:
<UIInputWindowController: 0x12f0be200>'
```

How can I get rid of this problem? I'm on iOS 8 (and don't support older versions).

**UPDATE:** I've created a git repository demonstrating the problem:

https://github.com/can16358p/CPInputAccessoryTest

Comment: The `inputAccessoryView` can't be added to any other view. Why are you adding it as a subview to the window in addition to making it the `inputAccessoryView`?

Comment: @rmaddy because if I don't, then it's not displayed.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu UIKit should take of displaying your input view.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr but it doesn't. If I don't add it to the window, it just disappears when editing begins.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Can you upload a sample project somewhere? This is impossible.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr I've created a repo demoing the problem. see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are abusing the `inputView` for something that it's not. The input view should be used for views the user an input data with, the input accessory view something you may want to extend that with. But its supposed be something like a keyboard.

Your text view is NOT part of that. It is the view the user is inputting data *into*. Decide if you want the view as an input view or in the main view hierarchy, but don't move it around before the two.

Your real problem is that you want to move the text view when the keyboard appears in order to keep it visible. To do so, observe the keyboard notifications

```
UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
```

and move your views around accordingly. You can adjust the view controller's view's bounds origin for example, to move everything up.

Comment: No, your suggestion is effectively the thing that I'm trying to avoid. I am trying to achieve what's here: http://derpturkey.com/uitextfield-docked-like-ios-messenger/

Comment: I can't get it to work. No matter what I tried, I couldn't get rid of that error. //by 'it' I mean my own project based on that one.

Comment: It apparently didn't work and I went back to this suboptimal solution. However, I used keyboard's frame change instead of will/did show/hide.

Comment: It is up to you to decide which notifications you listen to. I prefer the show/hide ones because they tell me whether or not I can ignore the frame key.

Comment: By the way, the reason that I was trying to get rid of this approach is to truly "dock" a custom view just on top of keyboard, just like FB Messenger. I don't know how they do it but it feels truly docked and is still smoothly attached to the keyboard when interactively dismissing the keyboard by vertical panning. With frame approach, I get a very close approximation but it's still not perfect.

Comment: Have you checked Messenger on iOS 9? Just proves how much of a hack they made.

Comment: Nope, haven't checked it yet. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the text view as an input accessory view of the entire view controller. See [my pull request](https://github.com/can16358p/CPInputAccessoryTest/pull/1).

Except for the growing text view part, this is pretty much the behavior of the Messages app.

Comment: I see. I've looked at your pull request by the way, I think you've removed the storyboard file but when I try to run it it asks for storyboard file and crashes.

Comment: Weird, it didn't crash for me. It should be fixed now.